# Mongoosastic Does not Index On Save

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, mongoose, mongoosastic

I have a mongoose model defined like this.

```
const custSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        es_indexed: true,
        es_type: text
    },
    phoneNumber: {
        type: String,
        es_indexed: true,
        es_type: String
    },
    email: String
})

custSchema.plugin(mongoosastic);

const Cust = module.exports = mongoose.model('Cust', custSchema);


Cust.createMapping(function(err, mapping) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        console.log(mapping);
    }
});

let count = 0;
const stream = Cust.synchronize();

stream.on('data', () => {
    count = count + 1;
})

stream.on('close', () => {
    console.log("Total " + count + " documents indexed");
})

stream.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log(err)
});
```

When I add new Collection to `Cust`, new document does not get added to elasticsearch unless I restart the server.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Please post your index _settings. Did you change the refresh time?

Comment: Nope, where can I find index_setting file?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-settings.html

Answer (score 1):

Struggled with this for a while until I discovered the issue was related to the ElasticSearch upgrade from v5 to v6, where "type" became a candidate for deprecation (removed entirely in v7) and no longer allows for more than one type. The library most likely forces its own "type" ("_doc" in addition to "customer" likely in your case), but we need to manually set the one type in mongoosastic as "_doc" (which is necessary for ElasticSearch v6).

First, delete your original index where the index and type may be causing the conflict.

Then, in your model, change

```
custSchema.plugin(mongoosastic);
```

to

```
custSchema.plugin(mongoosastic, {
  type: '_doc'
});
```

And create a new index after changing this option in the plugin section

```
stream.on("data", function(err, doc) {
  client.indices.create({
    index: 'customers',
    body: {
      doc
    }
  }, function (error, response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
```

Was a pain to resolve, hopefully this will help a few others avoid the headache as well.